# Not getting memory for Validator control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was reading an article to disable validators in Javascript using below mentioned reference

http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/08/11/87708.aspx

---

**My practice page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function RegexTester(ID) {
            debugger;
            var ID1 = document.getElementById('req');
            //            ValidatorEnable(
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="req" runat="server" ErrorMessage="hi" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
            ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{7,20}$" EnableClientScript="false">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Regex Tester" CausesValidation="false"
            AutoPostBack="true" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Query**

In the javascript function, I am unable to get the memory for required field validator control. I mean ID1 is showing null value...Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your validator is a server side control ASP.NET will create an unique client id for it based on control's id and its location in markup.

To get a client side id of your validator you should use:

```
<%=req.ClientID %>
```

Also there is a way to map all server side controls in a neat way:
http://jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/

If you are developing for ASP.NET 4.0 you can use ClientIDMode="Predictable" to have better control over how ids are generated.
More info at: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx